# Installing Linux on an Android netbook

Tags: linux, hardware, netbook

Is it possible to boot Puppy Linux using an USB stick on a netbook running Android, specifically this one: http://amzn.to/VSEJTf?

Is the right kind of BIOS in place that it can boot from USB?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to check if you can get some sort of boot menu, and if that one offers the option of booting from USB. Without putting my grubby paws on that machine, it's very hard to tell. I'd crawl all over the manufacturer's site looking for documentation.

If the machine runs Android, it is presumably ARM. I have no idea if Puppy Linux is available for that architecture (and AFAIK there is a bewildering variety of ARM-based machines around, and as things stand today it is almost that every board requires a custom built kernel, so this could turn out quite "interesting"...).

Please do tell (answering your own question if need be) how it turns out. Good luck!